# Primefaces DataTable selectCheckboxMenu filter formatting issue

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I copied the Primeface showcase for filters located here to my Local JBoss install:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml
But my selectCheckboxMenu for colors ends up looking like this

[image]

I'm using Primefaces 5.0. 
How can I get it to look like the demo on PF Showcase site?

[image]

**EDIT**

Changed to PF 5.1.RC1 but still no luck

Also tried increasing the width used by the demo for the p:selectCheckboxMenu but with this result

[image]

Comment: No IE 11 and Firefox 32.0.3.  But like I said the drop down is formatted correctly while viewing the Primefaces Showcase demo with the same two browsers

Comment: Ah ok, I was going to suggest you to try with new 5.1 version because some checkboxes had a similar bug: [related](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6577)

Comment: just before adding bounty I had changed to PF 5.1.RC1 but no luck.

Comment: Can't reproduce right now, did you try putting a higher width with `panelStyle` attribute of the `p:selectCheckboxMenu`?

Comment: It's more likely that your current CSS is missing up with the original one, I can't reproduce the problem ! http://imgur.com/sZLhgPv

Comment: @HatemAlimam, that was it.  Removing my CSS file fixed the PF issue.  Is the fix to find the offending entry in my CSS or change the loading order?  I'm going to see if I can find the offending CSS entry in my css file.

Comment: no the cascading is fine (order).. you need to look into either li or div wildcard rules ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was having the following entry in my custom CSS file which conflicted with the Primefaces.css

```
label {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    display: block
}
```