# primefaces selectCheckboxMenu display incorrectly

Tags: primefaces

I'm using `PrimeFaces 5.0, JSF 2.2 (Mojarra)`.

I tried this demo of selectCheckboxMenu: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/checkboxMenu.xhtml

But the component display incorrectly.

[image: selectCheckboxMenu display]

If I set the `panelStyle="width:300px"` instead of 250 the header (in green) display in one line but the checkboxes below still display incorrectly.

I use the bootstrap theme but the problem remain without theme.

And I don't use forward navigation.

Comment: Could you add your code here ?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876894/primefaces-datatable-selectcheckboxmenu-filter-formating-issue?noredirect=1#comment40942353_25876894) it's related to yours I think. it's more likely that you have a CSS role which missing up everything..

Answer (score 0):

Yes it was CSS problem

Here is the css properties that was disrupting the component

```
label{
  display: block;
  width: 130px;
  float: left;
}
```

Thank you all!